# How to remove single or multiple question mark from text using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using pandas-dataframe having `text` column. The column contains values like:

**Input:**

```
text
?
??
?????
??????
What is my account balance?
```

I want to remove rows that have only single or multiple questions?

**Output:**

```
text
What is my account balance?
```

I am using this code. But it remove everything.

```
data=data[~data['text'].str.contains("?",regex=False, case=False, na=False)]
```

How can I achieve this using python?

Comment: try `data[~data['text'].str.contains(r'^\?+',regex=True,na=False)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.Series.str.count()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) to count occurrences of `?` in each string of the Series. Then remove the rows that are all `?` by comparing the string length and occurrences num.

```py
data[data['text'].str.count("\?") != data['text'].str.len()]
```